# Regex pattern with (start of line or start of string or underscore)

Tags: regex

i wonder if you can help me with regex pattern...
in this input:

```
VEX_BLE_NW_maRIu
VEP_AS_maSAusz_TXZ
NE_lapKS_US
```

I want to find prefixes and Suffixes in those 3 names.
Like "VEX" "BLE" "NW" "VEP" "AS" "TXZ" "NE" "US"

My pattern is now `([A-Z]{2,3})[_\s]` I have a problem to make (start of line or start of string or underscore) and also (end of line or end of string or underscore or space)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<![^_])[A-Z]{2,3}(?![^_])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NaaoQq/1).

Alternative patterns are

```
(?<=_|^)[A-Z]{2,3}(?=_|$)
(?:_|^)([A-Z]{2,3})(?=_|$)
```

In case of `(?:_|^)([A-Z]{2,3})(?=_|$)`, the result is in Group 1.

*Details*:

- `(?<![^_])`  - either start of string or a location immediately preceded with `_`
- `[A-Z]{2,3}` - two or three uppercase ASCII letters
- `(?![^_])` - either end of string or a location immediately followed with a `_` char.